# Assign a value to char/unsigned char

Tags: c++

How can i assign a value to a char/unsigned char? I tried to do it with this code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char a;
    unsigned char b;
    std::cout << "Enter a and b: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << ":" << b << std::endl;
}
```

but it's printing only first two characters of variable **a** (i know that char can be one byte value, but i don't know why it doesn't want to accept my number and split it if it's bigger than 9)

Comment: Please provide example input and what output you expected vs what you are getting.

Comment: Code works fine [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2iB5qAGjny0plVsY).  Can you better describe what you want and why this isn't it?

Comment: What input did you give, what did the program print, and what did you expect? If I input 97 I get 9:7.

Comment: What do you mean, first two characters of variable `a`? Variable `a` can hold exactly one character. What is this "my number", and why do you expect a variable of type `char` to "accept" it, whatever that means?

Comment: If i enter for example "12" i get "1:2" and couldn't find why. Input should be something like "12" and "-40" in next line, expected output should be "12:-40". Sorry that i didn't say what i want exactly

Comment: You entered two characters, `'1'` and `'2'`. They got assigned to `a` and `b` correspondingly. Use `int` for variables that can hold integers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i would, but the exercise says that it has to be one byte integrer (signed and unsigned) without changing data types (int has 2 bytes, only char is good for it)

Answer (score 5):

> i know that char can be one byte value, but i don't know why it doesn't want to accept my number and split it if it's bigger than 9

There seems to be a misundertanding here.

A `char` can hold a byte but when you use

```
std::cin >> a;
```

only one character is read into `a`, not the integer value that reprsents a byte.

If your input is `95`, only the digit `'9'`, not the integer value `95`, is read into `a`.

---

Had `a` been a variable of type `int`,

```
std::cin >> a;
```

would read `95` into a. Of course, then there won't be the need for

```
std::cin >> a >> b;
```

That will expect the input for `a` and the input for `b` to be separated by one or more whitespace characters.

You can convert the `int` to a `char` by simply assigngment or explicit casting.

```
int i;
char a;
std::cin >> i;  // Provide 95 as input.
a = i;          // a is now the character that corresponds to 95 in the
                // encoding used in your platform.
```

Comment: Maybe mention that *if* `a` had been of type `int`, then the value `95` *would* have been stored in the variable (and why/what the difference is).